# extract string between character "[" and character "]" from text file using c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file which have data as below

```
[1] [apple] [market]

[2][toy]asdv[shop]sdvdsrdt
```

I only want the data between [ ]. those outside of the [] will be discarded. 
I have try the code

```
string[] lines = textBox1.Text.Split("[");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

but it say I have a char error.Is there any other code that I can use because the current code only will discard the character and thus not extract data only from []. the data is supposed to show in several textbox that I have created. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to using a regex, you can get the parts as an IEnumerable using Split() twice, once to get the start of each delimited string and once to cut off everything after the end delimiter in each resulting string;

```
var str1 = "[2][toy]asdv[shop]sdvdsrdt";

str = str1.Split('[').Skip(1)
          .Where(x => x.Contains(']'))
          .Select(x => x.Split(']').First());

foreach (var s in str)
    Console.WriteLine (s);

> 2
> toy
> shop
```

EDIT: To do it from file, you can just loop over [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx);

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("test.txt")) {

    IEnumerable<string> str;

    str = line.Split('[').Skip(1)
        .Where(x => x.Contains(']')).Select(x => x.Split(']').First());

    foreach (var s in str)
        Console.WriteLine (s);
}
```

Comment: I have try the code, it work on concole but I'm having problem when retrieving the data from a textfile.

Comment: @user3789007 Added an example of reading the data from a file. The `[]` sections are matched line by line since your example is only showing that. If they overlap line breaks, you could use [`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) which has the downside of loading the whole file into memory.

Comment: thank you, it is working. just a little more question. Can I select the data and put it to several textbox? example is the first data will be separate by 3 textbox. so the textbox will show the data 1, apple and market.

Comment: @user3789007 I'm not sure I understand the question. Instead of the loop, you could do `ToArray()` on the result and use the result as a regular array. Maybe that would make things easier if you're trying to populate several text boxes?

Comment: ToArray()?? Can't we just use the code and rearrange it to textbox?if cant how do I do the ToArray?? sorry, I'm new in this.

Comment: @user3789007 Of course you can replace `Console.WriteLine` with `textBox1.AppendText(s)`, however you're talking about multiple text boxes and I don't quite understand the problem so that I can help you. Maybe it would be better to start an entirely new question with the new problem, that will make it easier for you to describe what you need.

Comment: what I means is for the first line of data eg ([1] [apple] [market]), I would be able to show the data is separate textbox. value 1 in textbox1, apple in textbox2, market in textbox3. and another button that will remove the data from textbox and show the second line of data in the text file.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using `regex`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "[1] [apple] [market]";
            string s2 = "[2][toy]asdv[shop]sdvdsrdt";

            foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"\[(.*?)\]"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
            }

            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s2, @"\[(.*?)\]"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

[OUTPUT]
1
apple
market
2
toy
shop
```

Comment: I'm having problem when trying to extract the data from a text file. is there a way for me to take it from the text file? I'm able to show the text file to multitextbox but when I try your code, it produce error

Answer (score 0):

```
        string strLine = "[1] [apple] [market]";
        string[] arr1 = strLine.Split('[');
        foreach (string str in arr1)
        {
            string[] arr2 = str.Split(']');
            Console.WriteLine(arr2[0]);
        }
```